# String Manipulation using Power Shell

Tags: powershell

I have string below

```
1;#Chandler Bing 17;#Sheldon Cooper 18;#walter white
```

I'm trying to get user name from above string, in power shell
I want to remove numbers and ;#
please suggest some workaround

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replacing the unwanted characters is quite easy. You can use regex just leaving letters in your string. But to make your output useful, and export content to a csv-file - you may need to trim your output further.

Here's my suggestion:

```
$text = "1;#Chandler Bing 17;#Sheldon Cooper 18;#walter white"

Write-Host $text -ForegroundColor Yellow

# Replacing non-alphabetic characters with space
$pattern = '[^a-zA-Z]'
$stripped = $text -replace $pattern, ' ' 
Write-Host $stripped -ForegroundColor Gray

# Replace three spaces with comma (,) if you want to output the string to a csv-file
$stripped = $stripped -replace "   ", ','
Write-Host $stripped -ForegroundColor Cyan

# Replace two spaces with one
$stripped = $stripped -replace "  ", ' '
Write-Host $stripped -ForegroundColor Red

# Remove the initial comma (,)
$stripped = $stripped.trimstart(",")
Write-Host $stripped -ForegroundColor Green
```

This outputs the following:

[image]

Comment: Let me try this.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the names you can use following expression

```
("1;#Chandler Bing 17;#Sheldon Cooper 18;#walter white").Replace(/[^A-Za-z]+/g, '');
```

And here is the [link for string operation in powershell](https://4sysops.com/archives/strings-in-powershell-replace-compare-concatenate-split-substring/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also split a string that looks like id;#text;#id;#text like this:

```
$separator = ";#"
$option = [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries
$allLinks = yourstring.split($separator, $option)
foreach($entry in $allLinks) {
   write-host $entry
}
```